# ASP.NET Core 6, adding authentication and authorization only for specific controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there option that authentication / authorization is done only for specific controllers and for all other URIs it should be no authentication (anonymous)?

I have an OData endpoint with below implementation, but with below code, calling `https://localhost/odata/$metadata` returns a http 406 error.

But if I remove `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()`, then it works fine and shows the OData metadata page.

I want that AuthnN and AuthZ should be triggered only for my specific controllers.

Currently I have implemented as

```
/* presently in program.cs  *****/
builder.services.AddMyCustomAuthHandler()

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

/* in custom authentication implementation () ****/
public static void AddMyCustomAuthHandler(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
      //some custom logic.
    });
}

/* In OData controller ****/
[Authorize]
public class MyController : ODataController
{
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.allowanonymousattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Don't have the time to formulate an appropriate answer, but here's a summary:  Add any number of authentication providers.  They all run for every request.  Make sure that your providers add claims that are unique to each of them.  Then do claim-based authorization (look it up in MSDN) using the `Authorize` attribute.

Comment: If you do not decorate your controllers with [Authorize] they will not use authorization (in general - possibly you can configure this in other ways). Also as noted in a previous comment, you can also decorate specific controllers to allow anonymous access.

Comment: Read whole subsection on authorization, understand it, profit from having such knowledge forever [Introduction to authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: if you dont add `[Authorize]` to a controller and any of its actions, they should be accessible without any authentication or authorization. thats the default behavior anyway.

Comment: thanks all for comments. as mentioned in question it is not my custom controller it is Odata metadata endpoint for which i want to disable authentication. https://localhost/odata/$metadata

Comment: since 406 Not accepted is not 401 unauthorized or 403 forbidden, I question if auth* is the actual issue.  Is the 'not my code' metadata publicly available somewhere? It's impossible to tell what the actual problem is without more information.  On a long-shot, you could you can create your own handlers by deriving from `AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>` and `AuthorizationHandler` respectively where you can say "If it matches this route, pass all auth requirements by calling AuthenticateAsync() and HandleAsync()"

Comment: Given you don't want to require authentication for the metadata controller is is not enough to just swap `[Authorize]` for `[AllowAnonymous]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this via the following line of code, as used by my [example .NET API](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/host/startup/Startup.cs#L83).

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
});
```

This means you can apply the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to any public endpoints. All other endpoints fall back to the default secure configuration.

Answer (score 0):

define a custom authorization policy for controllers that require authentication and authorization in your Startup.cs file

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  {
   options.AddPolicy("RequireAuth", policy =>

    {
       policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
      // add any additional requirements such as roles if uou need 
  });
 });
```

apply the [Authorize] attribute with the policy to the controllers that require authentication

```
[Authorize(Policy = "RequireAuth")]
 public class MyController : ODataController
 {
 // Controller actions
}
```

configure authentication and authorization in your Startup.cs, but this time wrap it in a route-based check so that it only applies to specific routes

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
 endpoints.MapControllers();

 // Define a route for OData that does not require authentication and authorization
 endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel(),
    new ODataRoutingConventions(),
    new DefaultODataPathHandler()
    {
        UrlKeyDelimiter = ODataUrlKeyDelimiter.Parentheses
    });

  // Add other endpoints as needed
 });

 // Apply authentication and authorization globally
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
```